# Trouble signing up on google cloud platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am trying to sign up for the free trial on Google Cloud Platform.
I get to a page that looks like this:
[image: googleCloudPlatformPage]

I am unable to change the account type to *individual*.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have to give **United States** as country. Otherwise you will not be able to select ***Individual*** in the following step.

The problem afterwards is that you need to provide an address; and it has to be from the given country, as there is only a drop-down menu for the *state* field. Therefore, if you are not from the US, you would need to put a fake address, which is certainly not that nice and I don't know if it could bring problems in the future.

I did not find any additional info when googling this problem. Really strange...

Comment: i forgot to say that im from italy. so i selected my country, after doing that wasnt able to choose between the two options

Answer (score 1):

In the European Union, Google Cloud Services can be used only for business purposes i.e., if you are located in the European Union and the sole purpose for which you want to use Google Cloud Platform services has no potential economic benefit you should not use the service.

You can refer to FAQ for detailed answer:
https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/frequently-asked-questions